# CSS Nested class in id

Tags: html, css

I just followed a speed coding on YouTube for designing a card. I'm totally new to it, never designed once, I but have a little background to it (HTML & very basics CSS / JS). I copy & trace what is in the video on how it is done.

What stuck me is in this part: the `.profile` class cannot be accessed.
**How to do this right?** I tried separating it like

`#card-img-banner .profile{}` (It went out from the card)

[image: class]

HTML

[image: html]

I cannot proceed due to this, but from the video that I watched it applied to him - [Speed Coding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJqX8yG0wUU) time - 02:30

My work:

[image: out]

Comment: I guess you are missing a lot of closing braces, Please put your code instead of images.

Comment: use `#card-img-banner { position: relative; }`

Comment: The video doesn't use pure CSS but SCSS. Do you have Sass set up? And as a side note, speed coding videos might not be the best source material to learn from.

Comment: @Bhansa - I was annoyed by the code formatter. Not proper indentation. The curly braces are ok :)

Comment: @TamilSelvanC - Many Thanks it is fixed now, somehow.

Comment: @JJJ - Yes, you are right, but I have no choice. Yet I learn many things from speed coding - useful web resource. In YT there is no hmm.. somehow good tutorial for this one :(

Comment: Oh! I thought you are working with css, you should probably set up sass first.

Comment: @Bhansa - Does sass, support that nested thing? I'm still having trouble with it. I will install ruby then sass then.

Comment: yes it does, [Starting with Sass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-sass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
#card-img-banner { 
    position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: Do know how to enable `Sass` on Mozilla Developer ?